# Need help writing a regex

Tags: python, regex, expression

I need a regex that reads a file with blast information.
The file looks like:

```
****ALIGNMENT****
Sequence:  gi|516137619|ref|WP_017568199.1| hypothetical protein [Nocardiopsis synnemataformans]
length:  136
E_value:  8.9548e-11
score:  153.0
bit_score:  63.5438
identities:  35
positives:  42
gaps:  6
align_length:  70
query:  MIRIHPASRDPQTLLDPENWRSAAWNGAPIRDCRGCIDCCDDDWNRSEPEWRRCYGEHLAEDVRHGVAVC...
match:  MIRI  A+RD   LLDP NW S  W+ A  R CRGC DC       +     +CYGE + +DVRHGV+VC...
sbjct:  MIRIDRANRDHAELLDPANWLSFHWSNAT-RACRGCDDC-----GGTTETLVQCYGEGVVDDVRHGVSVC...
```

I already have a code, but in this file there is some extra data. The variable names with the corresponding name in this example, are:

```
hitsid = 516137619
protein = hypothetical protein
organism = Nocardiopsis synnemataformans
length = 136
evalue = 8.9548e-11
score = 153.0
bitscore = 63.5438
identities = 35
positives = 42
gaps = 6
query = MIRIHPASRDPQTLLDPENWRSAAWNGAPIRDCRGCIDCCDDDWNRSEPEWRRCYGEHLAEDVRHGVAVC...
match = MIRI  A+RD   LLDP NW S  W+ A  R CRGC DC       +     +CYGE + +DVRHGV+VC...
subject = MIRIDRANRDHAELLDPANWLSFHWSNAT-RACRGCDDC-----GGTTETLVQCYGEGVVDDVRHGVSVC...
```

I'm looking for something like this, this is a regex I already got, but now there are some extra things added:

```
p = re.compile(r'^Sequence:[^|]*\|(?P<hitsid>[^|]*)\|\S*\s*(?P<protein>[^][]*?)\s*\[(?P<organism>[^][]*)][\s\S]*?\nE-value:\s*(?P<evalue>.*)', re.MULTILINE)
```

File looks like:

```
****ALIGNMENT****
Sequence:  gi|516137619|ref|WP_017568199.1| hypothetical protein [Nocardiopsis synnemataformans]
length:  136
E_value:  8.9548e-11
score:  153.0
bit_score:  63.5438
identities:  35
positives:  42
gaps:  6
align_length:  70
query:  MIRIHPASRDPQTLLDPENWRSAAWNGAPIRDCRGCIDCCDDDWNRSEPEWRRCYGEHLAEDVRHGVAVC...
match:  MIRI  A+RD   LLDP NW S  W+ A  R CRGC DC       +     +CYGE + +DVRHGV+VC...
sbjct:  MIRIDRANRDHAELLDPANWLSFHWSNAT-RACRGCDDC-----GGTTETLVQCYGEGVVDDVRHGVSVC...

****ALIGNMENT****
Sequence:  gi|962700925|ref|BC_420072443.1| Protein crossbronx-like [Nocardiopsis synnemataformans]
length:  136
E_value:  8.9548e-11
score:  153.0
bit_score:  63.5438
identities:  35
positives:  42
gaps:  6
align_length:  70
query:  MIRIHPASRDPQTLLDPENWRSAAWNGAPIRDCRGCIDCCDDDWNRSEPEWRRCYGEHLAEDVRHGVAVC...
match:  MIRI  A+RD   LLDP NW S  W+ A  R CRGC DC       +     +CYGE + +DVRHGV+VC...
sbjct:  MIRIDRANRDHAELLDPANWLSFHWSNAT-RACRGCDDC-----GGTTETLVQCYGEGVVDDVRHGVSVC...

****ALIGNMENT****
Sequence:  gi|516137619|ref|WP_017568199.1| hypothetical protein [Nocardiopsis synnemataformans]
length:  136
E_value:  8.9548e-11
score:  153.0
bit_score:  63.5438
identities:  35
positives:  42
gaps:  6
align_length:  70
query:  MIRIHPASRDPQTLLDPENWRSAAWNGAPIRDCRGCIDCCDDDWNRSEPEWRRCYGEHLAEDVRHGVAVC...
match:  MIRI  A+RD   LLDP NW S  W+ A  R CRGC DC       +     +CYGE + +DVRHGV+VC...
sbjct:  MIRIDRANRDHAELLDPANWLSFHWSNAT-RACRGCDDC-----GGTTETLVQCYGEGVVDDVRHGVSVC...
```

Comment: what is the string you want to match in that file?

Comment: There are more section with the same lay-out. Added a part of the full content! 

And there not really a string I want to match, but I just want to 'sort' the data of the file with a regular expression.

Comment: Well, now, I think a regex is redundant  here: read by line, check if it is `***ALIGNMENT***`, build a list by splitting with `": "`, just get what you need (the first item can be later split with `|` and get the 1st and last iterms)

Comment: Yeah I know it's also possible in that way, but I already have a program based on a regular expression. (@Wiktor, you already helped me with a regex a few days ago, that one worked really good, but the content of the file changed, so that's why I need a new regex)

Comment: The difference is also that you did not mention there are multiple sections in the file. While a regex approach will work again after an update, it is not the best approach there is.

Comment: I think, as @WiktorStribiżew said, a solution working line by line will be easier to maintain. I don't know your regex from "a few days ago", but it seems like you have to rewrite lots of it.

Comment: I will show you what the "updated" regex could look like [here](https://regex101.com/r/wY5qI5/1). I do not suggest following this path here.

Comment: I used the regex I got from you to take, for example, all hitid's of each alignment, and then I added them in a list. So when I asked for the hit id list, I got all hit id's. That's why I needed the regex. In fact the whole program is ready now, the only thing is that the file content has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You no need regexp:

```
parsed = []
raw_parts = open('tmp9.txt','r').read().split('****ALIGNMENT****')
for raw_part in raw_parts:
 parsed_dict = {}
 for line in raw_part.split('\n'):
  try:
   key,value = line.split(':')
   parsed_dict[key] = value.strip()
  except:
   pass
 parsed.append(parsed_dict)
print(parsed)
```